# Webp image error when visit the link url path (domain/images/image.webp)

Tags: webp

I upload a Webp image (image.webp), it wors but error occured when try to view the image.webp by visit the link url path (domain/images/image.webp). The error code appear are below;

"RIFF‹
��WEBPVP8X
������]�E��ALPHè
��Çlõﬁü˚càà `øE≤†m;ÊÊãm€u≥àì⁄∂m∆Nm€j€∂mªç˙gˇ›Á ªÔÓv&3ﬂaDL�•ÿ÷ÛH“ãÇ F0ÒA0A0ÑÇ!Ç!|ÀYÇ ¡‹ÖdÂOOM‘2"&Äqn'µh∑€2¿BC-"

Please help me to fix it? so the image.webp available to view or download directly by visit the link url path.
For information the webserver run deb 10, apache2 and php-7